# get a file name in openfiledialog

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I use `OpenFileDialog` in VB.NET for importing file from C:\ , but when I choose my file , can I show ONLY the *file name* (not a complete path ) ?
[image]

I want to see only *namefile.pdf*, and **not** *c:....\namefile.pdf*

Here is my code:

```
fichier.Filter = "PDF Files|*.pdf|image files|*.png;*.jpg;*.gif"
If fichier.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
   fichier_txt.Text = fichier.FileName
End If
```

*fichier* is `OpenFileDialog` name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
fichier.Filter = "PDF Files|*.pdf|image files|*.png;*.jpg;*.gif"
If fichier.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
   fichier_txt.Text = Path.GetFileName(fichier.FileName)
End If
```

Comment: it work , thank you